# Number of days between two dates in Android

Tags: android, android-date

I need to calculate the number of days between two dates (both dates are also included) entered by a user in EditText. I also need to check weather these days are coming or has already passed. How do I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165564/calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-in-java

Comment: refer this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323792/android-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 15):

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String inputString1 = "23 01 1997";
String inputString2 = "27 04 1997";

try {
    Date date1 = myFormat.parse(inputString1);
    Date date2 = myFormat.parse(inputString2);
    long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    System.out.println ("Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First get the dates from two edit texts into String

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");

String firstDate=editText1.getText().toString();
String secondDate=editText2.getText().toString();
```

After that convert your string to  date..

The date difference conversion could be handled in a better way using Java built-in class, TimeUnit. It provides some utility methods to do that:

```
Date startDate =   myFormat.parse(firstDate);   // initialize start date
Date endDate   = myFormat.parse(secondDate); // initialize  end date

long duration  = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
```