# Calculating days between two dates in android

Tags: java, android

I am working with an application for counting remaining days between two dates,ie 
there is a start date and end date.I want to calculate remaining days to the end date in each day.Please help me.Thanks

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165564/calculating-days-between-two-dates-with-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323792/android-days-between-two-dates

Comment: i want to reduce the count in each day

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
String inputString1 = "23 01 2015";
String inputString2 = "27 04 2015";
try {
Date date1 = myFormat.parse(inputString1);
Date date2 = myFormat.parse(inputString2);
long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
System.out.println ("Days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this code only calculate days between date1 and date2..but i want to find remaining count between end date and start date in each day.