# Days difference between local date objects

Tags: android, date, time

```
LocalDate today=LocalDate.now();
```

And the event date is:
`eventDate=LocalDate.of(year, monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);` (from the date picker dialog)

I'm trying to calculate the days difference between them... The shortest thing I have found is this:

```
int DaysDifference = Period.between(eventToDisplay.getEventDate(),today).getDays();
```

While the first object is "today", and the second one is "eventToDisplay.getEventDate()." It didn't work for me, it showed the wrong number of days.

I have also tried to do it like this:

```
eventToDisplay.getEventDate().compareTo(today)
```

Also didn't work... 
I have also tried to do it without joda-time, because I had troubles with it, because of what I'm trying to do with date and time...

The other things I have found are long and complicated, and I thought maybe there is a better way, without the joda-time.

---

**EDIT:**

I have just tried this:

```
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar chosenDate=Calendar.getInstance();
            chosenDate.set(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().getYear(),eventToDisplay.getEventDate().getMonth().getValue(),eventToDisplay.getEventDate().getDayOfMonth());
            long def=  chosenDate.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
            long DaysDifference  =TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(def);
```

Didn't work for me

---

**EDIT:**
This has worked for me:

```
 LocalDate today=LocalDate.now();
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            now.set(today.getYear(),today.getMonthValue(),today.getDayOfMonth());
            Calendar chosenDate=Calendar.getInstance();
            chosenDate.set(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().getYear(),eventToDisplay.getEventDate().getMonthValue(),eventToDisplay.getEventDate().getDayOfMonth());
            long def=  chosenDate.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
            long daysDifference =TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(def);
```

Comment: what are your values

Comment: LocalDate today=LocalDate.now(), and the other one is a simple date from date picker dialog like: 3.3.2016

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323792/android-days-between-two-dates

Comment: Ty to parse your current date in same format as other date

Comment: When you can use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, you should *not* mix in `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Also your code using `Calendar` has a number of flaws, probably exactly because that class is so confusing and hard and counter-intuitive to use correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar end=Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(<year>, <month>, <day>);

    long def=  end.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();

    long days =TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(def);
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I have tried your answer but I have some issues with it

Comment: what is the problem ? because this solution has been tested

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Since you can use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, I warmly recommend that you stick to java.time. Calculating the difference is simple and straightforward when you know how:

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDate eventDate = LocalDate.of(2021, 5, 5);

    long differenceDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, eventDate);
    
    System.out.println("Difference is " + differenceDays + " days.");
```

Output when I ran today (APril 18 in my tme zone):

> Difference is 17 days.

If your date picker uses 0-based months (some date pickers insanely use 0 for January through 11 for December), remember to add 1 to the month number before passing it to `LocalDate`.

### What went wrong in all your attempts?

```
    int DaysDifference = Period.between(eventToDisplay.getEventDate(),today).getDays();
```

The `Period` class represents a period of years, months and days. Since months have different lengths, a `Period` does not correspond to any exact number of days, so it’s not the right class to use here. You tried to use its `getDays` method, which gives you the days component of the period, not the months or the years. So if the two days are less than a month apart, you will get the correct result, otherwise not. If for example the two dates are 1 month 3 days apart, you will only get the 3 days.

The `Calendar` class used in more than one of your attempts is poorly designed and long outdated. Counting days correctly with it would be truly cumbersome, so no wonder that your attempts gave the wrong results.

Both of your attempts are wrong for at least two reasons:

1. A `Calendar` has a date and *a time of day*. So by finding the difference in milliseconds and dividing by the number of milliseconds that you think are in a day, you will get different results depending on the time of day that happens to be in each of your `Calendar` objects. Your code calls `Calendar.getInstance()` twice. In an extreme situation your code may run across midnight so the time in the first `Calendar` will be close to 23:59:59 and in the second close to 00:00, which will almost certainly give you an error of 1 day.
2. A day is not always 24 hours. Summer time (DST) is the most frequent but not the only reason why a date is sometimes 23 hours, 25 hours or some other length. If for example you try to count days across the *spring forward* where a day is only 23 hours or 23 hours 30 minutes, your code will count 1 day too few.

Furthermore this line from the snippet that you say that works is definitely wrong:

```
    now.set(today.getYear(),today.getMonthValue(),today.getDayOfMonth());
```

You are using the 1-based month number from `LocalDate`, for example 4 for April, as a 0-based month number in `Calendar`, for example 4 would mean May. So your `Calendar` is off by 1 month. Since I haven’t got your complete code, is may in some cases balance out by another error that causes the other `Calendar` to be 1 month off too, I cannot know. Since months have different lengths, you will still get an error of up to 3 days sometimes.