# how to find difference between to dates in text view and show the number of days in some other textview

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have 3 text views 2 of them are to set the desired dates and when the 2nd date is set I want to calculate the number of days and display it in the 3rd text view. here is what I have tried

```
 checkInCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(ViewDetailsActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {

                            date1=(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                            date_in.setText(date1);


                        }
                    },mYear,mMonth,mDay1);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });

    checkOutCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePickerDialog2=new DatePickerDialog(ViewDetailsActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {

                            date2=(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                            date_out.setText(date2);

                        }
                    },mYear,mMonth,mDay2);
            datePickerDialog2.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog2.show();

        }
    });`
```

Comment: are you want to calculate days between two dates ?

Comment: yes the dates are in date_in and date_out but in the form of strings

Comment: so I think this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323792/android-days-between-two-dates